# How can I detect in Apex code that a user has or doesn't have access to the custom setting?

Tags: security, customsetting

I have created a new Custom Setting `Test__c` and enabled feature `Restrict access to custom settings` in `Schema Settings`.

Now I expect that a code in user context (Anonymous Execution Window) would return `false` value for a user who doesn't have access to the new Custom Setting `Test__c`, but it returns `true` even though the user doesn't have access to this custom setting neither by profile, nor by permission set. This user doesn't have `View All Custom Settings` permission either.

Why then the code

```
Test__c.sobjectType.getDescribe().isAccessible()
```

returns `true` for the user despite he doesn't have access to the custom setting?

How can I detect in Apex code that a user has or doesn't have access to the custom setting?